# Executing a query i got Two different results PhpMyAdmin and C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio, phpmyadmin

Hello if i execute the following query in PhpMyAdmin i have 5 Result.
If i execute the exactly query into C# i get back only 1 Result.
I have been beating my head against the table for 2 days but I can't find the solution.
Some ideas?

```
SELECT 
tbl_orders.Data_payment,
tbl_customers.City,
tbl_customers.Country,
tbl_orders.Price,
tbl_orders.state_order,
tbl_products.Product_ID,
tbl_products.Name
FROM
tbl_orders
    INNER JOIN
tbl_customers ON tbl_orders.fk_customer_id = tbl_customers.Customer_ID
    INNER JOIN
tbl_products ON tbl_orders.fk_product_id = tbl_products.Product_ID
WHERE
tbl_products.Product_ID = '2'
    AND tbl_customers.Country = 'Russia'
    AND tbl_orders.Data_payment BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2020-04-01'



        private void test_load(string query)
    { DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())    
                    {               
                        dt.Load(dr);
                        MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("err test_load " + ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how do you know that query is same? Try to debug or output it into messagebox to ensure you use same WHERE clause. Do you get "1" as dt.Rows.Count?

Answer (score 1):

After adding the database and testing the code you provided, I find that I still

can not reproduce your problem. I can get the same result in sql-query and in c# code.

You can see the following picture.

[image]

I also tested it, I find it is different from your picture.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jack, first thanks for your help.
Im preparing a clean database and c#  program that i will then share.

Comment: So here you can find the link to the project and DB https://yadi.sk/d/k4QXKjWzCTA5RQ
give a look to the image is show what i select as filter.

Comment: I have tested it, I find it is no problem.

Comment: i have no idea what is going on in my test, i always get only one result if executed by c# and more than one result if i use PhpmyAdmin or Mysql Workbench. I should also say that i use MariaDB 10 as a data base version    -> 10.3.21-MariaDB 
and as  Connector/NET   MySql.Data.MySqlClient .Net  8.0.19

Comment: I keep the same data but i change the 
Server type: from MariaDB to  MySQL  version: 5.6.35 and i also change the connector MySql.Data.MySqlClient  from 8.0.19 to  6.10.9 but still get only one result when they should be 2

Comment: and if i read  line by line  reader = command.ExecuteReader()  while (reader.Read())  .. i then get the right result of rows.

Comment: I only added three tables, I see you have many tables, so I guess that other tables may affect the result you get. Therefore, I suggest that you can create a new datatabase and only add the three tables data to see if it works for you. Anyway, my test results are normal。

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i finally solve the problem.

This pice of code in not working it return only one row and should return more than one.

```
        private DataTable test2_load(string query)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (MySqlDataReader data_reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {                     
                        dt.Load(data_reader);
                    }
                }               
            }
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("err test_load " + ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This is working. It return the right number of rows

```
        private void test3_load(string query)
    {
        MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new

         MySqlConnection(MyConString);
        mysqlCon.Open();

        MySqlDataAdapter MyDA = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        MyDA.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mysqlCon);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MyDA.Fill(table);

        BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
        bSource.DataSource = table;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
    }
```